# Dynamic where clause to filter collection elements

Tags: c#, linq, expression-trees

I have a collection `List<List<object>>`, which I need to filter out based on wheater the `List<object>` collection contains given element. I was able to build the where clause, but i get the following Exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: variable 'x' of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Object]' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined

I have found similar issues and i understand where the problem is, but i need help finding the solution.

Here is my code:

```
        protected override Expression<Func<List<object>, bool>> GetWhereClause()
        {
            var type = typeof(List<object>);
            var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");                

            Expression expressionBody = null;
            if (Verified)
            {
                Expression<Func<List<object>, bool>> expression = x => x.Contains("Verified");
                expressionBody = expression.Body;
            }
            if (GoodMatch)
            {
                Expression<Func<List<object>, bool>> expression = x => x.Contains("Good Match");
                if (expressionBody != null)
                    expressionBody = Expression.Or(expressionBody, expression.Body);
                else
                    expressionBody = expression.Body;
            }
            //More conditions here
            if (expressionBody != null)
            {
                var whereClauseExp = Expression.Lambda<Func<List<object>, bool>>(expressionBody, parameterExpression);

                return whereClauseExp;
            }

            return null;
        }
```

Now, this method generates the desired where clause, but when i try to apply it, i get the mentioned Exception.

```
        if (whereClause != null)
        {
            items = items.Where(whereClause.Compile());
            //
        }
```

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar use case requiring dynamic where clauses and used [Predicate Builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx)

Using it, you could do something like:*

```
private Expression<Func<List<T>, bool>> GetWhereClause<T>(T itemToFind){
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<List<T>>();

        if(Verified) {
            predicate = predicate.And(p => p.Contains(itemToFind));
        }

        if(GoodMatch) {
            predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Contains(itemToFind));
        }

        return predicate;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will a have a look tommorow.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a parameter from another expression 'as is' in a new expression. When you do:

```
Expression<Func<List<object>, bool>> expression = x => x.Contains("Verified");
expressionBody = expression.Body;
```

then you simply have the inline defined parameter x in the body. Now this parameter IS NOT the same parameter, that you defined before as

```
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(type, "x");
```

even if they both have the name x, that is not enough. Expression trees have reference equality.
So to get it to work, just use a visitor, that will replace the parameter with yours. Create a visitor:

```
public class ParameterUpdateVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private ParameterExpression _parameter;

    public ParameterUpdateVisitor(ParameterExpression parameter)
    {
        _parameter = parameter;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return _parameter;
    }
}
```

and then in your code use it like:

```
Expression<Func<List<object>, bool>> expression = x => x.Contains("Verified");
var visitor = new ParameterUpdateVisitor(parameterExpression);
expressionBody = visitor.Visit(expression.Body);
```

Of course this for every part that comes from another expression tree.

NOTE!!! this visitor is extra simplified, just for your example. If you have expressions that might have methods that have their own parameters, then make sure to replace only the parameter that you want to!
E.g. it wont work for:

```
Expression<Func<List<object>, bool>> expression = x => x.Select(o => o.ToString()).Contains("Verified");
```

because this visitor will replace the 'o' too. If you have this case, then pass in the parameter you want to replace (e.g. x, that is expression.Parameters.First()) in the constructor too, and only replace in the overridden method if node == myOldParameter.

BTW: why do you need expression trees if you compile the thing at the end anyways?